# Getting automatic profile pics for users in php?

Tags: php, facebook, api, profile, image

I have a list of names that I need to match with facebook profile pictures, without an access_token. 
Using 
`http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture` to get the pictures only seems to work if the user has a username.

Whats the best way to do this?

Also I took a look at pipl.com and they manage to fetch myspace and facebook profile images very easily with just a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the code I came up with:
You enter someones full name and it gets a profile image, given you have an access token.

```
<?php $fullname= get_the_title(); //gets users name
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.urlencode($fullname).'&type=user&access_token=...'); //Querys FB ID from facebook graph api
$lessdata = substr($data, strpos($data,'id":"') + 5); //Removes evrything before the start of the FB ID
$fbid = substr($lessdata, 0, strpos($lessdata, '"')); // removes everything after the FB ID
$fbimage = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fbid.'/picture'; echo '<img src="'.$fbimage.'"/>' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have names, you could use the graph API to search but unless the name is unique you will get back a lot of results potentially.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark%20zuckerberg&type=user&access_token=...

You can use any access token for that search, such as the one the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) gives you.

Comment: This is helpful, but how can I get the profile image of the top search result?

Comment: But haw can i do this directly in the php code. without transferring the user id over manually. Thanks for the response btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use get this in either way http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME/picture or http://graph.facebook.com/USERID/picture.